# Adding a item to a list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a debutant in JavaScript so please be patient with me, in this code I have a list of ingredients, when the user puts something in the input area and then click on the body, the text must be added as another item in the list before the last one, but my code is just not working and I can't find the problem.

```js
    function ajout(){
     var newingredient = document.createElement("li");
     var ingredient = document.getElementById("in2").value;
     var text=document.createTextNode(ingredient);
     newingredient.appendChild(text);
     var lastone=document.getElementById("last");
     var list=getElementById("listecommissions");
     list.insertBefore(newingredient, lastone);
    
   }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
   <head> 
   <title>kitchen</title> 
   <script type="text/javascript">

  </script> 
     </head> 
  <body onClick="ajout()"> 
   <br /><br /><br />
  <ul id="listecommissions"> 
   <li> 1kg de farine </li> 
   <li> un pack de lait </li> 
   
   <li id="last"> add one more ... </li>
  </ul> 
  <form>
   <input type=text id="in2" placeholder="add an ingredient"/>
  </form>
 </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: `onClick` should be `onclick`.

Comment: And on the definition for `list` it should be `document.getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

So, the main problem was this line

```
var list = getElementById("listecommissions");
```

which should be

```
var list = document.getElementById("listecommissions");
```

This is easily discovered when you use your debugger tools (Web Console). The second thing was that `onClick` should be `onclick`. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2o0w0h4s/) here.

---

I also would [recommend to separate JavaScript from HTML](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589) i. e. use no inline tags for JS. You can do this by adding a [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) EventListener to the `window` and within it add another [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the `body` (in your case) or better a button:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  document.getElementById('yourButtonIdHere')
    .addEventListener('click',function(){
      var newingredient = document.createElement("li");
      var ingredient = document.getElementById("in2").value;
      var text = document.createTextNode(ingredient);
      newingredient.appendChild(text);
      var lastone = document.getElementById("last");
      var list = document.getElementById("listecommissions");
      list.insertBefore(newingredient, lastone);
    });
});
```